# my login view doesn't work

Tags: python, django

in views.py :

```
def login(request):
   if 'username' in request.POST and 'password' in request.POST:
      user=User.objects.get(Username__exact=request.POST['username'],Password__exact=request.POST['password'])
      request.session['username']=user.Username
      request.session['lastlogin']=user.Lastlogin
      return render_to_response('airAgency/login.html',{'user':user})
   return render_to_response('airAgency/login.html')
```

in my template :

```
<form action="." method="POST" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 12px">
 <center><div dir="rtl" style="width:250px; height: 85px;">
     <div style="float:right;">
         <table style="width: 100%;">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     UserName :
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input id="username" name="username" type="text"/>&nbsp;
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     &nbsp;<label>Password: </label>&nbsp;</td>
                 <td>
                     <input id="password" name="password" type="password" />&nbsp;
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
     <input type="submit" value="Login" />&nbsp;
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;
                 remember me</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div></center>
 </form>
```

I enter a right username/password,but this doesn't return user to me,actually I check if user is returned to template,but it never return anythin to my template and of course it has no error! what's wrong with it
thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this form actually working? You need a submit button. Change the Button1 to a type of "submit" instead of "button".

Other things to check are that you actually have a user in the database, and that you are typing the username and password correctly, and case-sensitively.

Comment: yes,the user is right,and I changed the type to submit,but it doesn't work yet!!

Comment: OK, so have you tried going through to see what part errors out yet? Try sending some test data back to your template, such as whatever the value of request.POST['username'] was, to make sure that your form works. Just debug the code to find out which logic path it's going down, and what data it has when it does it.

Answer (score 7):

**DO NOT USE THIS.**

You have created your own user model, and appear to be storing passwords in plain text. This is very dangerous. Do not do it.

Django has a built-in user authentication framework, [fully documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/), which properly hashes passwords for security, and includes login forms. Use that instead. Even if you need more fields, use the built-in user model anyway and create a UserProfile model that includes your extra fields.

Comment: Totally agree with you. However, the issue that he ended up having was unrelated to it being a login form, and would've been a problem no matter what sort of form he was writing. So, a combination of the security of your answer with the quick change in my answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear you are checking that `user` is returned. To check if `user` is returned to your template, put `{{user}}` somewhere in your template.

Comment: yeah,I've cheked it,but I didn't put it's code here,now I edit my question!